# Is $7 + 5 \sqrt{2}$ a sum of squares in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, field-theory, contest-math, galois-theory

Is $7 + 5 \sqrt{2}$ a sum of squares in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$?

I believe it is probably not.

Suppose $7 + 5 \sqrt{2} = (a_1 + b_1 \sqrt{2})^2  + \ldots  + (a_n + b_n \sqrt{2})^2 $. By factoring out the common denominator $d$ we can assume that all $a_i, b_i$ are integers and replace $7 + 5 \sqrt{2} $ with  $7d + 5d \sqrt{2} $. Then I notice that

$a_1^2 + \ldots + a_n^2 + 2(b_1^2 + \ldots b_n^2)  $ is divisible by $7$

and

$2a_1b_1 + \ldots + 2a_nb_n$ is divisible by $5$.

I don't see any contradictions yet, though.

Comment: A sum of squares in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has to have non-negative image in any real embedding $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \to \mathbb{R}$. Now consider the embedding that sends $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan This is such a cool argument!